# How to make sure that part of code is run only by one thread (in openmp)

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I have a function that I need to make sure that when it is called, it in run only on one thread. So my function is something such as this:

```
 int ReadValue(int position)
 {
    // read data from a file 
 }
```

This function may be called from other functions that mayb at some stage be part of openmp parallel for .

I want to make sure that it is run only on one thread if it is called in a parallel way.

How can I do this?

Comment: That's called a "critical section"; what you need is thread synchronization. Read here: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#Synchronization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a full example (tested on 8 cores/threads):

```
#include <omp.h>

static int counter = 0;
int ReadValue(int position)
{
    // read data from a file one thread at a time
#pragma omp critical
    {
        // critical section code goes here
        ++counter;
    }

    return counter;
}

int main() {
    const int count = 1 << 20;
    // loop and raise protected counter
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        ReadValue(i);
    }

    // if counter was properly protected nothing will be printed.
    if (ReadValue(0) != count + 1)
        printf("failure!");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How to add  a name to it? Any example?